# ubuntu 22.04 on iMac 2012 - 27" - external screen and nvidia drivers

Tags: display, imac, unix

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an iMac 2012 fusion drive - to my great satisfaction. (Dual boot with OSX / MacOs Catalina)

The only problem I had was that I could not get an external 27" monitor to be detected. The external monitor does work OK on MacOs Catalina.

But I was able to solve it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502439/ubuntu-22-04-on-imac-2012-27-external-screen-not-detected-nvidia

[image: external monitor]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, you asked and answered your own question at "Ask Ubuntu". I do not believe you are permitted to ask and answer the same question here at "Ask Different". If this is permitted, then why do it again at "Super User", then again at "Unix & Linux"?

Comment: To me, these are the most relevant fora for people to look for answers if they engage with the same problem. The issue is about iMacs and about Ubuntu, hence imo these 2 fora make sense to me. I would not post it at Super User or Unix & Liniu or anywhere else. I think it helps people to repurpose old iMacs, they are great machines, it's a waste if they can't be used. I spent hours solving this, I hope it saves other people some time. I am not making money or trying to get clickbait or so. But if higher powers decide to close this, so be it.

Comment: You already asked and answered this on AskUbuntu, so anybody using the search engine of their choice will find it if necessary. There is no need to create stubs on other SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and try-outs and re-installs, I managed to solve this, with great help of many others and the internet in general.

Here you can find my solution:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502439/ubuntu-22-04-on-imac-2012-27-external-screen-not-detected-nvidia